# translation of nodes with 'g' key only working while it is held down

Tags: node-editor, interface

I'm using Blender 2.8 (2019-06-26 13:42)

In the node graph I used to be able to select nodes, press <kbd>G</kbd> then they would be 'grabbed' and move with the mouse until I left click to confirm or right click to cancel (in the same manner as the 3D view).

Now if I press <kbd>G</kbd> in the node graph then the nodes only move whilst <kbd>G</kbd> is held down. As soon as I release <kbd>G</kbd> the nodes are released. It applies to all node graphs, but it still works correctly in all other 2D/3D views.

How do I return to the previous functionality (ideally without having to reset to factory settings)? I think I must have pressed a keyboard shortcut that I didn't mean to.

Comment: Have you modified the keymap? The nodes in shading and compositing all keep following the cursor until left click.

Comment: I've just build the most recent master, it still has the expected behavior.

Comment: Can you check if the keymap entry for move in the node editor looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkxHC.jpg

Comment: @rjg is that under Graph Editor (Global)? If so then it looks identical

Comment: No under Node editor. Did you mean Graph editor though?

Comment: Yes, (I get confused thinking it's a node graph), but with the same settings as you I still get the problem on that installation of Blender 2.8 .

Comment: I have installed the latest version of Blender 2.8 (fancy installer now :O) and don't get the problem in that new installation. So it's not a big problem until I manage to mess it up again ;)